# reflection, create a specific object given an int

Tags: java, reflection, mapping

I have classes like `Dog.java`,`Cat.java`,`Bird.java`,`Fish.java`,`Not_Listed.java` etc. I also have a `ID.java` which only keeps some final int mapping:

```
public class ID{
  public static final int CAT = 1;
  public static final int DOG = 3;   // there maybe some integers skipped
  public static final int FISH = 4;   // but all integers are unique
  public static final int BIRD = 6;
  public static final int NOT_LISTED = -1;
}
```

All classes listed above extends `Animal.java` class.
What I need is given "6" I need to create a `Bird` object, given "1" I need to create `Cat` object. Given "2" or "5" I can return a `Not_Listed` object or simply throw an error(both works). I could simply do it with a `switch case` or `HashMap` but my list is somehow long and I dont want to update the code whenever my list grows. So I came up with reflection, but I have no idea how to do it?

Any other efficient solutions are also welcome. Sorry for being noob about reflection. Thanks in advance.

edit: IDs are **must**

Comment: I really don't see much difference in terms of maintenance between updating a HashMap, adding a field to an ID class, or adding an item to an enumeration.  The annoyance level is the same for each IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has Factory design pattern written all over it. You can register each Animal class (e.g. Cat, Fish, Dog, Bird, etc.) in their respective classes.

See **Class Registration - avoiding reflection** on http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

You can have an AnimalFactory that keeps a map of ID to class that implements Facotry Method. Then you would register it in each specific implementation of Animal. This way AnimalFactory wouldn't need to change, just each new Animal that is added would need to register the specific factory:

```
public class Dog extends Animal
{
    ...
    static
    {
        AnimalFactory.instance().registerAnimal(ID.DOG, new DogCreator());
    }
    ...
}

public class DogCreator extends AnimalFactory
{
    //Abstract factory method in AnimalFactory that gets called to return the Animal
    public Animal createAnimal
    {
        return new Dog();
    }
}
```

---

### Begin Edit

You can also have a generic Animal creator that uses reflection to make the new class (assuming each Animal has an empty constructor). This would still require you to register your specific id in each Animal implementation:

```
public class Dog extends Animal
{
    ...
    static
    {
        AnimalFactory.instance().registerAnimal(ID.DOG, Dog.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then AnimalFactory can use reflection to make the instance:

```
public Animal createAnimal(ID id)
{
    return animalMap.get(id).newInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need reflection for this.

Create an enum instead of your id class and have a class reference inside the enum, i.e.:

```
enum Animal {
     CAT(1, Cat.class),
     DOG(2, Dog.class),
     FISH(3, Fish.class);


     private final Class clazz;
     private final int id;

     Animal(int id, Class clazz) {
        this.id = id;
        this.clazz = clazz;
     }

     public Object generateInstance() {
         return clazz.generateInstance();
     }

     public class getGeneratedClass() {
         return clazz;
     }

     public int getId() {
         return id;
     }
}
```

This makes use of the feature of Java that allows enums to be fully featured classes and it records the `Class` to use within each entry in the enum. You can then use that `Class` to generate new instances on demand so long as the class has a 0-argument constructor.

To use this just do:

```
Animal.DOG.generateInstance() // Returns a Dog object
Animal.CAT.generateInstance() // Returns a Cat object
```

If you wanted to be able to get a type from id you could either build a `HashMap` inside the enum to do the lookup or just loop over the enum.values() looking for a match.

Comment: I have forgotten to say that ID matching is must. so I cant give up IDs.

Comment: So add an id to the enum too - in fact I'll add it to my example

Comment: What I need is more like : Dog mDog = (Dog) Animal.generateInstance(5); can we find something similar to that?

Comment: Yes, I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach so I'm doing it as a separate answer.

Just create a Map from id to class:

```
public static final int CAT = 1;
public static final int DOG = 3;   // there maybe some integers skipped
public static final int FISH = 4;   // but all integers are unique
public static final int BIRD = 6;
public static final int NOT_LISTED = -1;

Map<Integer, Class> classMap = new HashMap<>();
classMap.put(CAT, Cat.class);
classMap.put(DOG, Dog.class);
classMap.put(FISH, Fish.class);

public Object generateInstance(int id) {
     // Will throw NullPointerException if id isnt in map, you might want to consider some checks
     return classMap.get(id).generateInstance();
}
```

That will do what you want, you really should look at the enum design I posted in the other answer though - it will give much better results in the long term.

Comment: your both answers have given a lot to me except they did not fulfill the requirements of my situation. So I had to up only. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Upvote gives me nothing till after midnight (I'm on the rep cap), thanks anyway though :)